# Backbone: view's render method being called but DOM not updating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Look at this jsfiddle please: https://jsfiddle.net/76bypu9d/

As you can see, I have a list of players with strength, dexterity and intelligence. When I click the update button, I calculate the points based on inputs.

However the PlayerView is not being re-rendered although I have made the view listen to changes on the model:

```
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "<tr>",

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        var html = "<td>" + this.model.get("name") + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + this.model.get("job") + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + this.model.get("str") + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + this.model.get("dex") + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + this.model.get("int") + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + this.model.get("points") + "</td>";
        $(this.el).html(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

I can see see in console that the models are being updated with new value and that render method of the view is being called but the values in the DOM do not change. Any ideas why?

Comment: What version of backbone are you using? And if not the latest, is there any reason you couldn't use the latest?

Comment: Nevermind, stupid question. I see your fiddle is using 1.1.2. There are some optimizations to your code available based on that Backbone version. I'll see if I can include some in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not inserting the `PlayerView` `el`'s in the DOM. You're rendering each one as a string and concatenating that to render `PlayerTableView`. So there's no connection between the elements in the document and the `el` properties of the `PlayerView`'s. You should rework `PlayerTableView.render()` to insert the `PlayerView.el`'s.

Here's a quick diff from your code to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/76bypu9d/6/

Before:

```js
html += "</thead><tbody>";

_(this.collection.models).each(function( player) {
    var playerView = new PlayerView({
        model: player
    })
    html += playerView.render().el.outerHTML;
}, this);

html += "</tbody></table>";

$(this.el).html(html);
```

After:

```js
html += "</thead><tbody>";
html += "</tbody></table>";

$(this.el).html(html);
_(this.collection.models).each(function( player) {
    var playerView = new PlayerView({
        model: player
    })
    this.$el.find("tbody").append(playerView.render().el);
}, this);
```

And by the way, that string concatentation is hideous. You should look into a templating engine like mustache.

## Miscellaneous

Here's some miscellaneous notes about other aspects of your Backbone code:

- re: `tagName: "<tr>"`, `tagName` doesn't need angle brackets (`<` `>`). I guess it works, but it's not neccesary. It can be `tagName: "tr"`
- This: `_.bindAll(this, "render")` probably isn't necessary, and definitely isn't necessary for the sake of the line that follows: `this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render)`. From the backbone docs:

  > The `callback` will always be called with `object` as context.

  Where `object` is `this` in this case.

  Same thing with your `PlayerTableView` and `_.bindAll(this, "render", "updatePoints")`. The event handlers specified like:

  ```js
  events: {
      "click button": "updatePoints"
  },
  ```

  will be called with the view object as the context.
- Re: `$(this.el).html(html)` -- `$(this.el)` is unnecessary. You can do `this.$el`.
- This:

  ```js
  playersData.forEach(function( playerData ) {
      var player = new Player();
      player.set({
          name: playerData.name,
          job: playerData.job,
          str: playerData.str,
          dex: playerData.dex,
          int: playerData.int
      });
      that.collection.add(player);
  ```

  Could be consolidated to this (because you set `PlayerCollection.model`):

  ```js
  that.collection.add(playersData);
  ```
- This: `_(this.collection.models).each()` can just be `this.collection.each()`.
- And it bears repeating, the string concatenation has got to go.